Jenkins pipeline readJSON will read boolean false as null
Let say I have a JSON file myfile.json with this content:
{
    "vm": {
        "MyVal1": false,
        "MyVal2": true,
        "MyVal3": "some string",
    }
}

And my Jenkins pipeline looks like this:
pipeline {
    agent any

    options {
        ansiColor('xterm')
    }

    stages {
        stage('Parse VM details') {
            steps {
                echo "Read VM JSON file"
                script {
                    def props = readJSON file: 'myfile.json'
                    if (props['vm'].get("MyVal1") && (props['vm'].get("MyVal1") == true || props['vm'].get("MyVal1") == false)) {
                        env.MYVAL1 = props['vm'].get("MyVal1")
                    //} else {
                    //    env.VM_ERRORMSG = "MyVal1 is not a boolean."
                    }
                    if (props['vm'].get("MyVal2") && (props['vm'].get("MyVal2") == true || props['vm'].get("MyVal2") == false))
                        env.MYVAL2 = props['vm'].get("MyVal2")
                    //} else {
                    //    env.VM_ERRORMSG = "MyVal2 is not a boolean."
                    }
                    if (props['vm'].get("MyVal3")) {
                        env.MYVAL3 = props['vm'].get("MyVal3")
                    } else {
                        env.VM_ERRORMSG = "MyVal3 is not defined or empty"
                    }
                    echo "MyVal1 will be: ${env.MYVAL1}"
                    echo "MyVal2 will be: ${env.MYVAL2}"
                    echo "MyVal3 will be: ${env.MYVAL3}"
                    if (env.VM_ERRORMSG) {
                        echo "${env.VM_ERRORMSG}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

When I run the pipeline, I got this results:
[Pipeline] echo
MyVal1 will be: null
[Pipeline] echo
MyVal2 will be: true
[Pipeline] echo
MyVal3 will be: some string

So for MyVal2, I get back the boolean as true, but for MyVal1, it is always null, whatever I try. I tried env.MYVAL1 = toBoolean(props['vm'].get("MyVal1")) but it did not help.
Let say the JSON file is not too flexible, so I need to solve it in the Jenkins side. How could I make MyVal1 to appear as boolean even if it is false?
UPDATE:
As suggested in the comments, I found the reason why I get null instead of false. It is because during the testing, it does not enter into the if statement. If I change the corresponding lines in pipeline to:
if (props['vm'].get("MyVal1")) {
    env.MYVAL1 = props['vm'].get("MyVal1")
}
if (props['vm'].get("MyVal2"))
    env.MYVAL2 = props['vm'].get("MyVal2")
}

then still not enter in MyVal1, while in MyVal2, it enters. I don't understand the reason why it works this way, as I don't understand how else could I test that the variable is defined and not empty. If somebody knows the reason and/or have some suggestion to achive my goal, I open for them. :)

Are you sure that your script gets exactly this JSON? I wasn't able to reproduce this, MyVal1 is being set to false. Also, you can try to simplify the expressions just to props.vm.MyVal1 and so on - it also works.

The JSON file is the same, but in the pipeline, I had some ifs to determine it is a boolean or not. Now I edited the question and added the if statements there. My goal would be to have the check for the JSON variable and if it is correct, then add it to environment variable, if not, then store the error and I will process it later.

You need to double check your first if condition. It's not that Jenkins is unable to read the value - the null seems to appear because the real value was never assigned to env.MYVAL1.

Sounds logical and you seems right. But the question is still the question: what is wrong with that if statements? I can't imagine. Especially because MyVal2 works as expected with the same statements.

your "is boolean" validation is incorrect
consider the following code which corresponds to if statement in the question:
def x = false
if( x && (x==false || x==true) ){
  println "OK"
}

it will never print "OK" because x = false and first part of the if requires x to be true.
if( x && (x==false || x==true) ){
  //^ this requires x to be true or groovy "truth"
  println "OK"
}

the statement in updated question also not correct to validate if there is a value
if( x ){
  //^ this still requires x to be true or groovy "truth"
  println "OK"
}

more about groovy truth: https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#the-groovy-truth

so, to resolve an issue - it's better to rework if as this:
if( x==true || x==false ) {...}

or like this:
if( x instanceof Boolean ) {...}

and finally, the way you are getting properties could be simplified:
if( props?.vm?.MyVal1 instanceof Boolean ){ 
  env.MYVAL1=props.vm.MyVal1
} else {
  env.VM_ERRORMSG="MyVal1 is not a boolean" 
}


Thank you, it will do the trick, but in this case I lost the option to check "if defined" For example, if the MyVal1 is not defined in the JSON file, then the Jenkins pipeline will throw an error. This method only works if the variable is defined for sure. That is why I used the above method for the check.

if( props?.vm?.MyVal1 instanceof Boolean) should not throw exception even when MyVal1 not defined.

No, it will not: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: MyVal1 for class: groovy.lang.Binding

this sounds like unrelated (i'm not saying you are wrong). groovy.lang.Binding - informs that you are trying to get MyVal1 property without specifying the subject (so groovy tries to get it from current script. you can check if key is present in a map by props?.vm?.containsKey('MyVal1')

Thank you, if I do with that way, it is working. Strange it does not with the other way.
